# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - freezing on system loading

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 20.04, docking, dockstation

I have fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Everything is ok but I have my laptop on docking station and connected 2 monitors:

- 1st 29" LG by DisplayPort
- 2nd 24" Iiyama by VGA

When second monitor is connected system start and freez (It's start but it's look like loops)

Laptop:
[click to see neofetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIZ0P.png)